# How to get a list of all features/polygons from a KML file?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, kml

I use this code to load a KML file into OpenLayers:

```
var kmlLayer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
    projection: map.displayProjection,
    isBaseLayer: false,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "mykml.kml",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true,
            extractAttributes: true,
            maxDepth: 2
        })
    })
});
```

Now I have to list all names of the polygons included in this file.

Trying `console.log(kmlLayer.features)` I can see the features but I have no idea how to access them. Please see http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3148/2et4d7wf_png.htm because I'm not allowed to upload images yet.

How can I get name and description of those features?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well kmlLayer.features returns an array with all the features listed, so just accees them individually from the array like so: kmlLayer.features[x] - I don't completely get the question. What do you want to accomplish by accessing all Features? Just list the names?

Comment: kmlLayer.features[0] is undefined.Yes, I want to have a list of all names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the HTTP call happens asynchronously from your call to

```
kmlLayer.features[0]
```

So it seems empty. The solution would be to access the feature array only after the KML is loaded completely like so:

```
kmlLayer.events.register("loadend", kmlLayer, function (e) {
    console.log(kmlLayer.features[0].attributes.name)
    });
```

wether you use Firefox or Chrome just type into your developer web console kmlLayer.features[0] after you loaded the map and it will tell you that it is in fact not undefined.

Let me know if this helped!

Answer (score 0):

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/doc/faq.html#why-aren-t-there-any-features-in-my-source-

They've seem to have released a solution to this problem for v3 of the API, use the 'change' event and listen for 'ready'.